# AngularJS. Можно ли данные из ng-repeat записать в переменную?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular2, angularjs-controller

```
<span ng-repeat="item in vm.order.okeds">{{item.code}}</span>
```

На выходе получаем:
01
02
03

Можно ли записать их в переменную, например vm.okedCode;
Значение которой равнялось бы (01,02,03).

Comment: они у тебя уже есть в переменной _vm.order.okeds_